# I am getting some error when building my angular universal app with npm run build:prerender

Tags: angular, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

i am trying to build my angular universal app using npm run build:prerender but i am seeing two errors here.

## errors

1. It complains of not seeing the rout path i set as `"**"` for null page
2. It displaying this below error too .

   **binding.copyFile(src, dest, flags);
                                          ^
   Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, copyfile 'C:\wamp64\www\naipod4\dist\browser\assets' -> 'C:\wamp64\www\naipod4\dist\static\assets'**

please what should i do, i am stuck here for almost one week now

Comment: the first error, check whether have you set ** for a defined component. and second error might be fixed if you give `write permissions` to `C:\wamp64\www\naipod4\dist\`

Comment: please how do give the write persion?

Comment: Please navite to Output window in VS, and share with us your output.

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/give-permissions-to-files-and-folders-in-windows/78ee562c-a21f-4a32-8691-73aac1415373

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error when I upgraded node to > v8

```
fs.js:1919
  binding.copyFile(src, dest, flags);
```

The solution was to upgrade my npm packages using npm audit fix I am not sure which of the many packages upgraded solved the problem